# Equivalence of relations between two probability measures

Tags: probability, logic, solution-verification

Suppose we have two probability measures $P$ and $Q$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ satisfying
$$
\forall A\in\mathcal{F},\quad P(A)<0.1 \Rightarrow Q(A)<0.1.
$$
Is this equivalent to
$$
\forall A\in\mathcal{F},\quad P(A)>0.9 \Rightarrow Q(A)>0.9?
$$
It seems yes because $P(A)<0.1 \Leftrightarrow P(A^c)>0.9$ and the same implication holds for $Q$.

Comment: Yes, you answered your own question. You probably should tag questions like this with verification or something like that. Since it seems you just needed a sanity check.

Comment: @ManateePink Thanks for confirming my intuition.